# Getting child and grandchild users from mysql query

Tags: mysql

Actually I have a table called users and I have to pull out the child and grandchild users of a specific user like I am trying to get child and grandchild users of user with id 44 and I tried this query but it is giving me some extra users even they are not child or grand child of user 44:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id`='44' OR `parent_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id`='44' OR `parent_id` IN (SELECT `id` AS 'curret_id' FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id`='44' OR `parent_id` IN (SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id`='curret_id')))
```

Here is CREATE TABLE Syntax for my table if it helps:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `join_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `fname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `lname` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `dob` date NOT NULL,
  `user_type` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: give your CREATE TABLE syntax, some sample data and expected output

Comment: It is there now

Comment: what is 'curret_id' in your original SQL

Comment: I am getting child id as current_id look at the query like : SELECT `id` AS 'curret_id' FROM `users` WHERE `parent_id`='44'

Comment: look at recursive queries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a MySQL hierarchical recursive query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20215744/how-to-create-a-mysql-hierarchical-recursive-query)